# Evaluate the integral of $\frac{e^{−z}}{(z^2)}$ around the circle |z| = 2

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions, singularity

Not too sure how to approach this exactly. I think the biggest problem is working out whether or not the function is holomorphic, because from there I can use the appropriate method, but I would appreciate any hints about that too.

Answer (score 3):

The integrand is holomorphic (I just checked), which you can check using the C-R equations.

**Method 1: [Integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)**
$$\int_C \frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}dz,$$ where $z=2e^{i\theta}$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Then $dz=2ie^{i\theta}d\theta$, so that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-2e^{i\theta}}}{4e^{2i\theta}}2ie^{i\theta}d\theta=\frac{i}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2e^{i\theta}-i\theta}d\theta=\frac{i}{2}(-4\pi)=-2\pi i.$$
I used Mathematica to evaluate the last definite integral, but it seems tricky to perform by hand.

**Method 2: [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)**

The residue of the integrand at $z=0$ is $-1$, so

$$\int_C\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}dz=2\pi i\sum_{\text{residues}}=2\pi i(-1)=-2\pi i,$$
as expected already.

**Method 3: [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) (differentiation formula)**

Using the formula $$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz,$$
with $f(z)=e^{-z}$, $a=0$ and $n=1$, then $$\int_C\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}dz=2\pi i f'(0)=-2\pi i.$$

As pointed out in a previous answer, Method 3 is probably the most straightforward approach, depending on taste.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you!

Comment: @mathsisfun123 Welcome to Maths SE. You can upvote/accept answers if you find them helpful and/or useful !

Comment: The residue method turns out to be what I needed. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Is the function $f(z)=e^{-z}$ holomorphic?

By Cauchy's theorem for derivatives
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}dz=f'(0)2\pi i=-2\pi i$$

Comment: I think this is the problem, I'm not quite sure. I would think that it is, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: What is its derivative? Where is its derivative defined?

Comment: it's derivative is $-e^{-z}$, defined everywhere and hence it's holomorphic?

Comment: Yes, so $\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}$ satisfies the conditions for one of Cauchy's theorems

Comment: This helps, thank you

Comment: @mathisfun123 I edited in the use of the Cauchy Theorem for derivatives, you already did the work in computing $f'(0)$ in the comments, so in my opinion this is simpler than the residue method

Comment: great, thank you so much for your help