# Compute using residues $\int_{|z|=3}\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Compute using residues the integral of the following function over the positively oriented circle $ |z|= 3 $

$  f \ (z) = \dfrac{e^{-z}}{z^2}
$

Solution:
The only singular point of $f$ in $\left |{z}\right |\le 3$ is $z=0$ (double pole) and its remainder is therefore

$\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0}\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2-1)!}\left(\displaystyle\frac{e^{-z}z^2}{z^2}\right)^\prime=\displaystyle\lim_{z \to 0}-e^{-z}=-1$

Consequently, $\displaystyle\int_{|z|=3}f(z)=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=-2\pi i.$

this right? I hope I have done well, and that the result I have given is satisfactory

Comment: Your answer is correct. For your particular example there are easier ways to estimate the residue using the fact that the factors in your funciton $f$, that is $e^{-z}$ and $z^2$ have well known expansions: $f(z)=z^{-2}\Big(1-z+\tfrac{z^2}{2}+\ldots +\tfrac{(-z)^n}{n!}+\ldots=\tfrac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z}+\tfrac12+\ldots\tfrac{(-1)^nz^{n-2}}{n!}+\ldots$ From this, it becomes easy to read out the coeffiicient that accompanies the term $z^{-1}$. Try for example this technique with $g(z)=z^{-3}e^{z^2}$ of $h(z)=z^{-2}\cos(z)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate the integral of $\frac{e^{−z}}{(z^2)}$ around the circle |z| = 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760919/evaluate-the-integral-of-frace%e2%88%92zz2-around-the-circle-z-2)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, although it is simpler, in order to compute the residue, to note that$$\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}=\frac{1-z+\frac1{2!}z^2-\frac1{3!}z^3+\cdots}{z^2}=z^{-2}-z^{-1}+\frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}z+\cdots$$and that therefore, by definition,$$\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2}\right)=-1.$$